# Why # can not use in java identifier?

Tags: java, identifier

Please let me explain that # can not use in java identifier.
For example. int e#;

And also, let me know that # is used in java and where to use?

Comment: Is there any point to this question? Why are you concerned about `#` specifically?

Comment: every programming language has its syntax. Simply it works this way. As well as you can't have variable like `int 1d;` try to live with that :)

Comment: I'm not sure about a usage in Java, but in [javadoc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#multiple@see) the # is used to separate Classes and the member Field/methods.

Comment: I'd advice against using this except for purposes of amusement. But you can use *all* unicode "letters" in a Java identifier, including ones that merely look like a hash-sign. So this is valid: `int c井 = 5;`

Answer (score 4):

Because it's not a valid symbol in the language.  Just as you can't do:

```
int HELLO+*/\Variable;
```

See *3.8. Identifiers in the Java specification:*

An identifier is an unlimited-length sequence of Java letters and Java digits, the first of which must be a Java letter.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to read this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Ask Oracle afterwards, if you still don't know!